# Fancyhdr: ToC Header

Tags: header-footer

My Master's Thesis has a ToC spanning over three pages. The header is defined as.

```
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape{My name here.}}
```

This works fine for all sections (incl. LoF, LoT). It prints the section name without numbers in the left head, and my name in the right head.

Now there is one problem. On page one and three of the ToC, the left head is "Table of Contents". On page two, however, the head is "CONTENTS". Any suggestions on how to solve this? I'd like to have "Table of Contents" on page two, too.

Here's how the ToC is included:

```
\newpage
\markright{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\markright{Table of Contents}
```

So apparently the first `\markright` is responsible for the header on page one, and the second `\markright` for the header on page three.

EDIT: A minimal example included below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}[0pt]

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


% Header
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape{My name here}}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\markright{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}                   
\markright{Table of Contents}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 5}

\newpage
\section{Study Site}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 4}

\newpage
\section{Data}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}

\newpage
\section{Methods}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 4}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 5}

\newpage
\section{Results}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 5}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}

\newpage
\section{Discussion}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 4}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2} 
    \subsection{Subsection 5}
    \subsection{Subsection 6}               
    \subsection{Subsection 7}

\newpage
\section{Conclusions}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page one]

[image: Page two]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of sniplet, a full example makes it a lot easier for others to test your code. For example the document class is very important here, but you don't specify anything

Comment: Hi daleif, thanks for your answer. The document class is article. I'll try to create a full example.

Comment: This is not a minimal, others do not have access to the files you are inputting. Please make this self contained. You can use the kantlipsum and its `\kant` command for sample contents

Comment: Edited again. I haven't included any blind text, since it doesn't seem to be important. I have, however, recreated the structure of the thesis with sections and subsections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\makeatletter\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\makeatother
\tableofcontents
\makeatletter\let\@mkboth\markboth\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for MWE! without it I would not have studied your question.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much for your help! :))

Comment: please help, after this command \markboth does not stop at the content and goes to the next page where it should not be.